# Xamarin ScrollView: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility is ignored on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a ScrollView which I want to always show the horizontal scroll bar. e.

I set 
`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Always`
but that does not seem to make any difference. I have also tried setting the `ScrollBarFadingEnabled = false`, setting the `ScrollBarFadeDuration = 1000000000` and setting `ScrollBarDefaultDelayBeforeFade = 1000000000`but none of these properties seem to make any difference.

I have been able to achieve similar behavior in the past for VERTICAL scroll bars, and have even used and effect to change the size and color of the VERTICAL scroll bar. Is there some issue with the HORIZONTAL scroll bars for ScrollView in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change `styles.xml` file in your Android project to keep them on and visible, like this:

```
<item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack">true</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarSize">18dp</item>
```